# Retrieve a date field and give value to a new field using Javascript Button

Tags: javascript, date, button

I am trying to retrieve the date from a field (which is a user input field) in a Campaign Member, and give that value to a new date field.

```
{!REQUIRESCRIPT
("/soap/ajax/13.0/connection.js")}

var records = {!GETRECORDIDS($ObjectType.CampaignMember)};
var newRecords = [];

if (records[0] == null)
{
    alert("Please select at least one row")
}
else
{
    for (var n=0; n<records.length; n++) {
    var CampaignMemberObj = new sforce.SObject("CampaignMember");
    CampaignMemberObj.id = records[n]; 

    CampaignMemberObj.New_Start__c = new Date("{!CampaignMember.Course_Date__c}");

    newRecords.push(leadObj);
}
result = sforce.connection.update(newRecords);
if (result[0].success=='false') 
{   
    alert(result[0].errors.message);
} else 
{
location.reload(true);
}
}
```

An error is returned that of FaultString:"Nan... which indicates that it is not returning a number.

Any suggestions?

Comment: You're getting a string with this: {!CampaignMember.Course_Date__c} Can you do a console.log('{!CampaignMember.Course_Date__c}'); and reply back. You're probably going to have to parse the string into a JavaScript date.

Answer (score 0):

Look at the getDate() method on picture[image]

Got it from https://success.salesforce.com/answers?id=90630000000gwhCAAQ

Comment: Thanks - but the above code gives oppty.CloseDate the value of TODAY.  I want to take the date from an existing field (in my example it is CampaignMember.Course_Date__c and put it into another field (which is type date) in the above example this is CampaignMemberObj.New_Start__c

Comment: My fault, didn't read the given solution properly.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks - but the above code gives oppty.CloseDate the value of TODAY.

I want to take the date from an existing field (in my example it is CampaignMember.Course_Date__c and put it into another field (which is type date) in the above example this is CampaignMemberObj.New_Start__c

So I need to take the value from "{!CampaignMember.Course_Date__c}" and put it into CampaignMemberObj.New_Start__c

Do you know how to do that?

Comment: This is not an answer, so please add a comment rather than answering.